# How to add several HTML tags into one div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using Javascript, I've pulled a value from an XML document and I'm trying to generate as many  tags as the value I've pulled is. I assume I would go about doing this using a for loop, but when I tried this, it would only display one image.

```
for(i=0; i<red; i++){
   document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = "<img src='slike/red.png'></img>";
}
```

I'm aware of why this isn't working, but I couldn't find a solution myself, so I'm wondering what Javascript function do I need?

Comment: Have you tried using `+=` instead of just `=` ?

Comment: If you want to append to the string, use `+=` instead of `=` (shorthand string concatenation). You could also use DOM manipulation methods, such as `.appendChild`.

Comment: You should consider using a `DocumentFragment` instead.

Comment: +1 for document fragment. re rendering DOM with every push is a waste

Answer (score 4):

Use string concatenation:

```
html = '';
for(i=0; i<red; i++){
   html += "<img src='slike/red.png'></img>";
}
document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = html;
```

You could also use `+=` when assigning to `.innerHTML` in the loop, but that's less efficient because the browser has to format and reparse the DIV contents each time. It's better to do it in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you think about it logically, it seems that what you've coded is for the innerHTML of red to change "red" number of times. You're not adding the img "red" times, you're just changing it to that one image "red" times.

So, why don't you do this instead:

```
var numberImages= "";

for(i=0; i<red; i++){
    numberImages += "<img src='slike/red.png' />";
} 

document.getElementById("red").innerHTML= numberImages;
```

Answer (score 1):

each time it assigns a single vaue to the innerHTML of the element.

use the below instead.

```
var elem=document.getElementById("red");
for(i=0; i<red; i++){


       elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML+"<img src='slike/red.png'></img>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be adding a large number of elements to the DOM, you should be using a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) to avoid any unnecessary reflows. Here's a quick example ([and a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sellmeadog/9mJLV/)):

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'slike/red.png';

    fragment.appendChild(img);
}

document.getElementById('red').appendChild(fragment);
```

What this allows you to do is create as many elements as you need and add them to the DOM in batch which will only reflow the DOM once.